# Bulk update order status in WooCommerce every XXX hours

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

- I'm trying to programatically update all order status every 6 hours.
- There are 3 custom status after 'complete', each to be updated in sequence every 6 hours.
- I created a cron to run every 6 hours calling function 'auto_update_orders'.

Would it be better to do it this way or a direct SQL query? If done via SQL query, would the automatic emails for the custom statuses still be sent out?

```html
function auto_update_orders() {

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'complete',
);

$orderList = get_posts($args);

foreach ($orderList as $orderPost) {

    $order = new WC_Order($orderPost->ID);

    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'inprogress2' );
    }
    elseif ( $order->has_status( 'inprogress2' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'inprogress3' );
    }
    elseif ( $order->has_status( 'inprogress3' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'ready' );
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: by using the `WC_Order` object is the best way, instead of running direct `SQL` query. `WC_Order` `update_status`  calls many other functions

Comment: Thanks...would the code above be correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Added and executed but nothing.

Comment: use `wc_get_orders` in place of `get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use more of the built-in WooCommerce functions. Someday Woo will move orders to a custom table (really thought it would've happened already) and `wc_get_orders()` will stay compatible.

```
function auto_update_orders() {

    $args = array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => array( 'complete', 'inprogress2', 'inprogress3 )'
    );

    $orderList = wc_get_orders($args);

    foreach ($orderList as $order) {

        if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
            $order->update_status( 'inprogress2' );
        }
        elseif ( $order->has_status( 'inprogress2' ) ) {
            $order->update_status( 'inprogress3' );
        }
        elseif ( $order->has_status( 'inprogress3' ) ) {
            $order->update_status( 'ready' );
        }

    }

}
```

I've been playing with the action scheduler all week. It might be a nice choice here to chunk this down into smaller batches depending on how many orders you can expect `wc_get_orders()` to return.

Comment: I added this and executed via Advanced Cron Manager and no changes to the completed orders.

Comment: Nevermind... 'status' => array( 'complete', 'inprogress2', 'inprogress3 )' to 'status' => array( 'completed', 'inprogress2', 'inprogress3' )
Thanks!

Comment: Note: The `save()` method is already used in [`update_status()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#318-347) method...